# setInterval with each() function=

Tags: php, jquery, each, setinterval

This is my first post :) I've searched for an answer to my problem, but with no results (or atleast I think so). Im creating a list for bookings. I want the code to hide passed times, highlight this time, and keep the other divs as they are (it seems like it works as it should). When all that is done, i also want it to update itself. As soon as the time pass a time, it will move on without a need for an update (setInterval?).

how can i make this possible?
Thanks in advance!

```
// Get THIS hour.
var now = new Date;
var hour = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();

if(hour < 10){ hour = '0' + hour; }
if(minutes < 10){ minutes = '0' + minutes; }

var klockan = hour + ':' + minutes;

$('.bokning').each(function(){
    var divTimme = parseInt($(this).text().substr(0, 2), 10);
    if(divTimme < 10){ divTimme = '0' + divTimme; }
    var divMinut = parseInt($(this).text().substr(3, 2), 10);
    var tid = divTimme + ':' + divMinut;
        if(klockan >= tid){ 
            $(this).attr('name', 'passed'); 
        }

});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you have a specific problem with the code? At the moment this sounds like a list of requirements

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the help to see how and what to ask. We prefer a [mcve] which in your case means, hit the `<>` in the editor, add HTML, script and CSS instead of PHP, since this has likely nothing to do with PHP and add the actual result versus the expected result. Search for javascript timer if you need such a thing

Comment: Wow, you guys answered fast :) Im sorry if i didnt make it clear what i want with this. I went here, to see how i can use my jquery with setInterval.. Ill edit my post :) Thanks